# SSE2: How To Load Data From Non-Contiguous Memory Locations?

Tags: performance, optimization, assembly, sse, simd

I'm trying to vectorize some extremely performance critical code.  At a high level, each loop iteration reads six floats from non-contiguous positions in a small array, then converts these values to double precision and adds them to six different double precision accumulators.  These accumulators are the same across iterations, so they can live in registers.  Due to the nature of the algorithm, it's not feasible to make the memory access pattern contiguous.  The array is small enough to fit in L1 cache, though, so memory latency/bandwidth isn't a bottleneck.

I'm willing to use assembly language or SSE2 intrinsics to parallelize this.  I know I need to load two floats at a time into the two lower dwords of an XMM register, convert them to two doubles using `cvtps2pd`, then add them to two accumulators at a time using `addpd`.

My question is, how do I get the two floats into the two lower dwords of a single XMM register if they aren't adjacent to each other in memory?  Obviously any technique that's so slow that it defeats the purpose of parallelization isn't useful.  An answer in either ASM or Intel/GCC intrinsics would be appreciated.

EDIT:

1. The size of the float array is, strictly speaking, not known at compile time but it's *almost* always 256, so this can be special cased.
2. The element of the float array that should be read is determined by loading a value from a byte array.  There are six byte arrays, one for each accumulator.  The reads from the byte array are sequential, one from each array for each loop iteration, so there shouldn't be many cache misses there.
3. The access pattern of the float array is for all practical purposes random.

Comment: You're probably looking for the `gather` instruction (there's a whole family there, depending on your CPU model. Haswell should have some nice improvements there)

Comment: @Leeor: I don't think that `gather` is part of the SSE2 instruction set.  Isn't it AVX2?  dsimcha, is AVX2 available on your machine?

Comment: @NathanFellman, ah, sorry, I missed that as a restriction

Comment: Start by trying `_mm_set_ps` or `_mm_set_pd` and see what code your compile generates (with optimisation enabled) - it may surprise you.

Comment: What is the size of the small array (e.g. float x[16]).  Is there so regular access pattern (e.g x[0], x[4], x[8], x[12]) or is it random?

Comment: Tell us more about the layout pattern of these floats in memory. If they are regularly spaced, maybe interleaved processing is possible ? Can you provide pseudo-code ?

Comment: Question: given how small your "small array" is, why aren't you storing the values as `double`s and avoiding the cost of conversion?  Given that your data layout prevents vectorization, the conversions are actually more expensive than the loads are.

Comment: Good question.  I tried to simplify the problem for this post, but it's actually a matrix and the row changes on every loop iteration.  The whole matrix usually fits in cache, but using doubles might make it not fit for some relatively large matrices.  Interesting idea, though.  Perhaps for sufficiently small matrices I could speed this up by using doubles, if the doubles would still fit in cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this specific case, take a look at the unpack-and-interleave instructions in your instruction reference manual. It would be something like

```
movss xmm0, <addr1>
movss xmm1, <addr2>
unpcklps xmm0, xmm1
```

Also take a look at `shufps`, which is handy whenever you have the data you want in the wrong order.

Comment: Thanks.  This seems like the least-bad answer.  I've come to the conclusion that getting a real-world speedup out of this is basically impossible, though, because vectorizing would let me sustain a thoughput > 1 floating point add per clock cycle if there weren't any other bottlenecks, but on Sandy Bridge/Ivy Bridge you can't do more than one floating point load per cycle anyhow.

Comment: @dsimcha, It's perhaps the least bad answer because you provided insufficient information to answer the question.  Agner Fog has a SSE/AVX/AVX2 gather function called `lookup` in his Vector Class Library which can be efficient to use in cases for arrays with size known at compile time.

Comment: @dsimcha, and SB/IB can load two 128-bit words per clock cycle.  So at a minimum you can get two non-contiguous floats per clock cycle.

Comment: @Zboson:  My mistake.  I looked this up in AF's tables.  Sandy Bridge can do two movss instructions from memory per cycle but only one from register.  This is weird but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be interesting to see how this performs using the `lookup` functions from [Agner Fog's Vector Class Library](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#vectorclass).  It's not a library you need compile and link in.  It's just a collection of header files.  If you drop the header files into your source code directory then the following code should compile.  The code below loads 16 bytes at a time from each of the six byte arrays, extends them to 32-bit integers (because the `lookup` function requires that), and then gathers floats for each of the six accumulators.  You could probably extend this to AVX as well.  I don't know if it this will be any better in performance (it could be worse).  My guess is that if there was a regular pattern it could help (in that case the `gather` function would be better) but in any case it's worth a try.

```
#include "vectorclass.h"    
int main() {
    const int n = 16*10;
    float x[256];
    char b[6][n];
    Vec4f sum[6];
    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) sum[i] = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<n; i+=16) {
        Vec4i in[6][4];
        for(int j=0; j<6; j++) {
            Vec16c b16 = Vec16uc().load(&b[j][i]);      
            Vec8s low,high;
            low = extend_low(b16);
            high = extend_high(b16);
            in[j][0] = extend_low(low);
            in[j][1] = extend_high(low);
            in[j][2] = extend_low(high);
            in[j][3] = extend_high(high);
        }
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++) {
            sum[0] += lookup<256>(in[0][j], x);
            sum[1] += lookup<256>(in[1][j], x);
            sum[2] += lookup<256>(in[2][j], x);
            sum[3] += lookup<256>(in[3][j], x);
            sum[4] += lookup<256>(in[4][j], x);
            sum[5] += lookup<256>(in[5][j], x);
        }
    }
}
```